# Troubles calculating $\int_z^\infty\mu\mathrm e^{-\mu y}(\mathrm e^{-\lambda z}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda y})\ \mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've difficulties calculating the following integral

$$\int_z^\infty\mu\mathrm e^{-\mu y}(\mathrm e^{-\lambda z}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda y})\ \mathrm{d}y$$

I'm gonna use her to find a joint distribution of two random variables. I've try to apply the following substitution $u=e^{\lambda y}$ but I couldn't do much after that.
I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This substitution is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int_u^\infty e^{-at}dt=-\left.\frac{e^{-at}}a\right|_u^\infty=\frac{e^{-au}}a.$$

Your integral is

$$\mu e^{-\lambda z} \int_z^\infty e^{-\mu y}dy-\mu\int_z^\infty e^{-(\mu+\lambda) y}dy.$$

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two terms. $e^{-\lambda z}$ is constant in the first integral. So the answer is  $e^{-\lambda z}e^{-\mu z}-\frac {\mu} {\lambda+\mu}e^{-(\lambda+\mu)z}$

Comment: $-\frac{\lambda  e^{-z (\lambda +\mu )}}{\lambda +\mu }$ is shorter